# Running Oracle Stored Procedure from C# Error

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am new to oracle. I created a stored procedure to fetch table data.

```
create or replace
procedure GETLATESTNEWS(cv_results in out sys_refcursor)
as
begin
open cv_results for
select news from tbl_newsdetails;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-99999,'Not Inserted due to :'||SQLERRM);  
end;
```

The procedure got compiled successfully. But in my .net code I am getting error

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETLATESTNEWS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

My .net code is

```
con.ConnectionString = constring;
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "GETLATESTNEWS";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

What might be the issue?. I am able to insert with insert stored procedure. But select is not working.

Comment: Your stored procedure requires a parameter (of sys_refcursor) but you are not passing anything. Please check [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322160)

Comment: OK..Will read it and let you know.

Comment: PLEASE. Keep in mind that link is just to show you where lies your problem. You should investigate further because the Microsoft Oracle .NET provider is deprecated now and you should work with the latest [Oracle NET provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) by Oracle

Comment: Thanks Steve. It was a mistake from my end. Infact I am very much used with sqlserver. So moving all of a sudden has caused the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("cv_results", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it is working for me

```
OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand();
oraCommand.Connection = oraConnection;
oraCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oraCommand.CommandText = "procedurename";
OracleParameter oraParameter = new OracleParameter(":result", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
oraCommand.Parameters.Add(oraParameter);
oraCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

OracleDataAdapter oraDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oraCommand);
Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor refCursor = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor)oraParameter.Value;
OracleDataReader reader = refCursor.GetDataReader();
```

but if you return stored procedure as ref_cursor.